# Application protocol design

Tags: tcp, protocols

I'm discovering TCP communications and I'm looking on how I will structure data for client/server parsing

Every request have a token, a command and arguments.

What I'm thinking: `AUTH_TOKEN: 123456 CMD: doSomething ARGS: {user_id: 1}\n`

The `ARGS` can contain arrays, hashes

Is the right way or there is design pattern's to do that ?

Comment: There's no _"the right way"_. There's a way that works, and many that don't. Does this work? Good. Doesn't it? Why not? It seems you have chosen `\n` as message separator, are you sure your token, command and args don't ever contain that character?

Comment: I suggest reading some RFCs for common internet protocols. SMTP might be a good one as it has support for authentication. The should lead you onto SASL which is about pluggable authentication methods and shows how a simple protocol can be extended to support TLS. HTTP and MIME are other to look at. Make sure you pin down things like the byte order for binary protocols, encodings for text, line-endings for line oriented protocols.

Comment: Ok, so my choice was JSON since it's really easy to serialize/deserialize data between our C++ app & webservice.